# Problem using ODBC for PostgeSql in Goldengate Console with dblogin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, odbc, oracle-golden-gate

Hello my name is manuel I have a problem using the ODBC for PostgreSql in Goldengate, I have connection using isql -v DSN but in the goldengate console I can not access using the dblogin, I have seen a similar question for which they say that the DriverUnicodeType=1 is placed to solve the problem and if it solves the previous problem but now I get another error
which is the following
ERROR OGG-03039 Database character set U is not supported.
It is worth mentioning that my architecture is in AWS having GG in an EC2 instance and PostgreSql in RDS in the same VPC.

here is my ODBC.ini

```
[test]
Description=PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so
Trace=No
TraceFile=/tmp/psqlodbc.log
Database=postgres
Servername=xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
UserName=postgres
Password=password
Port=5432
ReadOnly=Yes
RowVersioning=No
ShowSystemTables=No
ShowOidColumn=No
FakeOidIndex=No
ConnSettings=No
DriverUnicodeType=1
TransactionErrorBehavior=2
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of GoldenGate you are using, but with GoldenGate 19.1 and 21.1, it does not use the PostgreSQL driver, but uses a DataDirect driver that is packaged with GoldenGate.  See this doc for info to see if that helps.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/21.3/gghdb/preparing-database-oracle-goldengate-postgresql.html#GUID-C4C055B9-D0D4-4B5A-B611-1E919BB2040E